# Better performance when saving large JSON file to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have an issue.

So, my story is:

I have a 30 GB big file (JSON) of all reddit posts in a specific timeframe.
I will not insert all values of each post into the table.

I have followed [this series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvOnYLDg8_Y), and he coded what I'm trying to do in Python.
I tried to follow along (in NodeJS), but when I'm testing it, it's way too slow. It inserts one row every 5 seconds. And there 500000+ reddit posts and that would literally take years.

So here's an example of what I'm doing in.

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(location)
oboe(readStream)
    .done(async function(post) {
        let { parent_id, body, created_utc, score, subreddit } = data;
        let comment_id = data.name;

        // Checks if there is a comment with the comment id of this post's parent id in the table
        getParent(parent_id, function(parent_data) {
            // Checks if there is a comment with the same parent id, and then checks which one has higher score
            getExistingCommentScore(parent_id, function(existingScore) {

                // other code above but it isn't relevant for my question

                // this function adds the query I made to a table
                addToTransaction()

            })
        })
})
```

Basically what that does, is to start a read stream and then pass it on to a module called [oboe](http://oboejs.com/).

I then get JSON in return.
Then, it checks if there is a parent saved already in the database, and then checks if there is an existing comment with the same parent id.

I need to use both functions in order to get the data that I need (only getting the "best" comment)

This is somewhat how `addToTransaction` looks like:

```
function addToTransaction(query) {
    // adds the query to a table, then checks if the length of that table is 1000 or more

    if (length >= 1000) {
        connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
            if (err) throw new Error(err);

            for (var n=0; n<transactions.length;n++) {
                let thisQuery = transactions[n];
                connection.query(thisQuery, function(err) {
                    if (err) throw new Error(err);
                })
            }

            connection.commit();
        })
    }
}
```

What `addToTransaction` does, is to get the queries I made and them push them to a table, then check the length of that table and then create a new transaction, execute all those queries in a for loop, then comitting (to save).

Problem is, it's so slow that the callback function I made doesn't even get called.

My question (finally) is, is there any way I could improve the performance?

(If you're wondering why I am doing this, it is because I'm trying to create a chatbot)

I know I've posted a lot, but I tried to give you as much information as I could so you could have a better chance to help me. I appreciate any answers, and I will answer the questions you have.

Comment: Ummmm.....you need a database and some data filtering to query only what is needed at a given time

Comment: @charlietfl well, I could get all the data, but the problem would be the memory.

Comment: That's why you want to use a database and query what you need

Comment: Did you measure all steps independent? If so, there is a very fast way to load data in mysql. See "LOAD DATA INFILE", which should load a set like this in a few minutes (assuming a reasonable amount of data in GB).

Comment: Is the JSON file just a bunch of mysql queries, ie `INSERT INTO` etc? Or is it actual reddit data formatted in JSON that you are trying to transfer into a database?

Comment: @PatrickEvans It is reddit data formatted in JSON that I'm trying to transfer into a database.